# Add list elements in DOM to array in JS

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I have a un-ordered list containing links with the same class and a unique ID, I need to add all those ID's to an array in javascript with.

```
<ul>
<li><a class="item" id="10" href="#"></a></li>
<li><a class="item" id="11" href="#"></a></li>
<li><a class="item" id="12" href="#"></a></li>
<ul>
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easier (more mootools-like) way to do what @Dimitar did:

```
var ids = $$('.item').get('id');
```

Good Luck

Comment: how is that a more mootools-like way? first,`$$` actually maps to `this.document.getElements` so that's slower. 2nd, this is a less-qualified selector and less performant in browsers that lack `querySelectorAll` (IE) as it has no getElementsByClassName either so .item will walk ALL NODES. and thats where performance really matters... head to head, `$$(".items").get("id")` vs `document.getElements(".items")` the latter wins. interestingly, this made me discover a FF4 bug in mootools: http://jsperf.com/ff4-mootools-slick-test/2 - whereby `.item` over-performs. in all other browsers, its reversed

Comment: i didn't say it was faster.. $$ is just an alias, and i dont think the time to process that alias is considerable http://jsperf.com/ff4-mootools-slick-test/3 you could use `$$` without worrying about performance.. your 2nd point is true, is easier for the browser to find more specific selectors but that doesn't mean that using `$$` is slower.. besides i've added a new test using `$` and `getChildren` and it was the fastest (except on IE).. and finally the question had "mootools" written on the title and in the tags XD But i've learned a few thing from your comment Thxs Cheers!!

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, `$$` is now frowned upon and discouraged as a best practice (just like any of the other $-based constructs that got deprecated in 1.3) and it is being kept on for legacy's sake - you won't find a single call to $$ in mootools-core (but it's still in mootools-more). The real drama **IS** performance in browsers like IE where you don't have any shortcuts Slick can use like `getElementsByClassName`  and `querySelectorAll`. For the new gen browsers, selector speed is deemed 'high enough' anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
var ids = document.getElements("ul li a.item").get("id");
console.log(ids); // ["10", "11", "12"]
```